# SQL Project Testing After Deployment

Tags: sql-server-2008, unit-testing

In **SQL Server Database Project** I have several views

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwDB1_Table1]
AS 
SELECT
    0 as Id,
    0 as Col1,
    0 as Col2
```

and in postdeployment i am modifying these views

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vwDB1_Table1]
AS
    SELECT Id, Col1, Col2 FROM DB1.dbo.Table1
GO
```

the reason I am doing this is because of visual studio IntelliSense and prevent build warnings (maybe it will not build at all)

but the problem is that sometimes (it is rather an exception) the views are not modified and application start throw errors.

therefore I would like to ask if there is possible to have some kind of tests (Unit, Integration) which will after deploy (or manually) check, if the SELECT is success (returns more then 1 row).

any idea ? I am totally unexperienced with testing.

Comment: Integration tests usually require your application to be started; in your case, the fact that the application fails to even start is a feedback strong enough in itself - what would you gain if you would be able to gather the same feedback through a test instead of when trying to start the application?

Comment: the problem is that only some subpages are failing, which are using the views and also if all tests are okay in test environment it can fail after deployment to production, therefore I want to have additional after-production-deploy tests